Table position in list of symbols
I am trying to make a list of symbols for my master's thesis. However, the table keep going down on the page, leaving a large space between the section name and the table, like below: 
The code is also attached:
\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{List of Symbols}%
\section*{Latin Symbols}%

\begin{table}

    \begin{tabular}{ l l l } 

        $C_{Battery}$&Capacity of the Battery& $\si{\ampere\hour}$\\

        $d$&Diffusion path length& $\si{\nano\meter}$\\

        $d_{eff}$&Effective diffusion path length& $\si{\nano\meter}$\\

        $F$& Faraday's constant& C/mol\\

        Fr.&Friction&\%\\

        $h_{\nu}$&Planck energy at frequency $\nu$& J\\ 

\end{tabular}

\end{table} 

I would appreciate any help.
Regards

remove the table enviornment, you don't want a float here

also C_{\mathrm{Battery}}$ and d_{\mathrm{eff}}}  never use math italic for words, as you can see in the image you posted.

Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.
